# How to make a native C executable run forever in the Android?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, executable

Is there a way to make a native C executable run forever (in background) in Android OS?
I have ported libpcap in Android and I made a sniffer. I have a rooted HTC Hero. I run the sniffer in the background through this commands:

```
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw -t vfat /dev/block//vold/179:0 /sdcard
# /sdcard/mysniffer &
```

I simultaneously run an Android service that browses a list of web pages in a loop fashion. To force my service run forever in the background I acquire a [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) via android.os.PowerManager.

The service runs forever in the background but the sniffer is killed from the OS after some time of running..

Is there a way to make it run forever? I want both of these programs running always in the background so as to do some measurements.

Comment: Holding a partial WakeLock does not keep your service alive - it just prevents the CPU ever sleeping while your service is running. This behaviour will **destroy** battery life. A standard service runs until you stop it; if it is destroyed by the Android system due to low memory then it is recreated later when more memory is available.

Comment: yes, but in my service I use a timer (which I call it in onCreate) to dump in a file some values every 5 minutes. When I don't acquire a partial WakeLock, then if I run the service for 2 hours, then the file will have not all the values until this time.. Moreover, how I can run a native executable forever? is this possible?

Comment: In that case, why can't you use an alarm service that wakes it up every 5 minutes to dump the file?

Comment: Ok, I also have a loop in the service that continuously browses URLs.. I thought that an alarm service will be more expensive in terms of CPU load than a simple timer that runs inside my service.. But I am not sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, and conduct my experiments and measurements! :) I just changed the [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) with a [SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK) in my service!
I can't understand the reason, but by doing this the native sniffer is not killed by 
Android.. If someone knows a better solution, please let us know.